# "Bluetooth failes to initialize" when automating Bluetooth steps

Tags: java, bluetooth, codenameone

I'm trying to create a class that sequentially performs the Bluetooth tasks without user intervention aside from starting the process. In this class an external event calls the overridden method "executeCentral" from there it calls setup() to enable and request permissions. If they complete successfully the initialize() method is called and waits for one second before calling the Bluetooth initialize() which is executed in the EDT. If it runs without exception it calls startScanning() which also waits 1 second before calling Bluetooth startScan()  in the EDT. After scanning has started it waits 10 seconds before calling Bluetooth stopScan() in the EDT.

I recreated the project for a clean setup and used the "downloader" in the Codename One Settings. It compiles successfully and runs, but reports an exception on "Bluetooth not initialized"

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? I'm under the impression that all calls must be done in the EDT.

The single form BTDemo compiles and executes each task as a separate user initiated event.

```
public class UITaskBluetoothEx extends com.crumptech.library.mobile.ui.tasks.UITaskBluetooth {

protected Bluetooth bt = new Bluetooth();
protected Map devices = new HashMap();

public UITaskBluetoothEx() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String getReplacement() {
    return "UITaskBluetoothEx";
}

protected void showDebug(String message) {
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            UIApplication.showDebug("UITaskBluetoothEx " + message);
            completed(result(false));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void executeCentral() {
    bt = new Bluetooth();
    try {
        setup();
        initialize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showDebug(e.getMessage());
    }
}

protected void setup() throws IOException {
    if (!bt.isEnabled()) {
        bt.enable();
    }
    if (!bt.hasPermission()) {
        bt.requestPermission();
    }
}

protected void initialize() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (!bt.isInitialized()) {
                            bt.initialize(true, false, "ShopMyLocalStores");
                        }
                        startScanning();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        showDebug(e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}

protected void startScanning() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (!bt.isScanning()) {
                            bt.startScan(new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject res = (JSONObject) evt.getSource();
                                        if (res.getString("status").equals("scanResult")) {
                                            if (!devices.containsKey(res.getString("address"))) {
                                                devices.put(res.getString("address"), res);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }, null, true, Bluetooth.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER, Bluetooth.MATCH_MODE_STICKY, Bluetooth.MATCH_NUM_MAX_ADVERTISEMENT, Bluetooth.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES);
                            stopScanning();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        showDebug(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}

protected void stopScanning() {
    try {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (bt.isScanning()) {
                                bt.stopScan();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            showDebug(e.getMessage());
                        }
                        showResults();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 10000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

protected void showResults() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String text = "";
                    Iterator it = devices.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                        text += (pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue() + "\r\n");
                    }
                    UIApplication.showDebug(text);
                    completed(result(true));
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some methods currently aren't supported on iOS.  These will throw IOExceptions if they are called on iOS.  This is a limitation that is baked into the Cordova plugin that we ported.  These methods literally return "Unsupported Operation" inside the plugin.  I'm not sure if these are just omissions of the plugin, or if they can't be supported. The list of methods that are currently unsupported on iOS are:

1. isEnabled()
2. enable()
3. disable()
4. mtu()
5. requestConnectionPriority()
6. hasPermission()
7. requestPermission()
8. isLocationEnabled()
9. requestLocation()

I have marked these in the javadocs for the Bluetooth class to help identify them. We'll likely have to do something here to clean it up ... perhaps an exception is not the best thing.

In any case, your test app is failing because you call isEnabled() and initialize() inside the same try/catch block.  isEnabled throws an exception so it never gets to initialize() and your tests aren't run.

I have adapted your code into my own test case, and made that modification, and it appears to run fine.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Instead of throwing an exception I would suggest that if the status comes back as anything other than what is expected return false, and store the error message in a string that can be accessed by the caller; something like bt.getLastError(). It the error is "unsupported option" then the caller will have the option to continue.